# How to set a null value inside a drop-down selection without "parent_id" required

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**I would like to make a drop-down selection with the first selection comes with " NO PARENT ID REFERRED " and set as null value and pass into database in laravel**

Here is my code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="bit_app_policy_category_parent">Parent Category</label>
    <select id="bit_app_policy_category_parent"  name="parent_id" class="form-control">
        <option selected disabled>Please select one option</option>
        @foreach($parents as $parent)
            @if ($parent-> status != 'Freeze')
                <option value="{{ $parent->id}}">{{$parent->description}} </option>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="bit_app_policy_category_status">Status<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <select id="bit_app_policy_category_status"  name="status" class="form-control">
        <option value="Active">Active</option>
        <option value="Freeze">Freeze</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Dropdown selection[image]`

Expected result = 
Please select one option
-----No parent ID referred-----(able to choose and pass value into db)
description 11 and so on .

[image: Database be like]

**PLEASE NOTE THAT IM UNABLE TO USE FORM METHOD AS MY LRAVEL UNABLE TO UPDATE DUDE TO SPECIFIC PURPOSES**

[image: Database structure]

Comment: @Julian Stark i cant see review ur edited file dude that i dont have 2k reputation

Answer (score 1):

try to add another `<option>` before `foreach`.

example codes:

````
<option value="null" selected>Please select one option</option>
@foreach($parents as $parent)
     @if ($parent-> status != 'Freeze')
         <option value="{{ $parent->id}}">{{$parent->description}} </option>
     @endif
@endforeach
</select>
    ```
````

Comment: Thanks for helping me btw , but still got errror as i set a filter before that must refer to an integer
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'null' for column `company_policy`.`bit_app_policy_category`.`parent_id` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `bit_app_policy_category` (`id`, `code`, `description`, `parent_id`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, 123, 123, null, Active, 2019-11-06 03:09:37, 2019-11-06 03:09:37))

Comment: It's a database issue. You should change the `parent_id` column default value to `null` or the `parent_id` should be `nullable`

Comment: can teach me how to change it ? much appreciated, im using XAMPPS

Comment: i have added my database structure into it , can u help me look over ?

Comment: in PphMyAdmin -> Go to your database table -> Select `Structure` -> click `change` link of `parent_id` in the list -> you can see the `null` checkbox or `Default` dropdown (select `Null` or check the checkbox) -> save

Comment: in `Default` Select `As Defined` -> Enter your default value (I recommend `0`) -> save

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`company_policy`.`bit_app_policy_category`, CONSTRAINT `bit_app_policy_category_parent_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `bit_app_policy_category` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `bit_app_policy_category` (`id`, `code`, `description`, `parent_id`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, G46MR, 123, 0, Active, 2019-11-06 03:38:23

Comment: If you set the default value to `0` instead of `null` your database tries to resolve the foreign key constraint with value `0` which failes. Try to set the default value to `null`

Comment: yeah i have followed ur way, but still errors saying that 

Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'null' for column `company_policy`.`bit_app_policy_category`.`parent_id` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `bit_app_policy_category` (`id`, `code`, `description`, `parent_id`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, 123, 123, null, Active, 2019-11-06 06:27:50, 2019-11-06 06:27:50))
http://localhost:8089/category